# How to create a time-space diagram showing how data is transferred in TCP?

Tags: networking, tcp, network-programming

I need to draw a time space diagram of a client connecting to the server, then requesting data, and server sending x bytes of data then server closing the connection.

First, I am not sure exactly how many trips back and forth there would be, I am thinking:

1. Client requests connection
2. Server accepts
   3  Client sends ACK
3. Client requests data
4. Server sends x bytes of data
5. Client sends ACK
6. Server closes connection
7. Client sends ACK

Is that correct??

Also, I need to specify  SEQ, ACK numbers and SYN/ACK/FIN bits, I get the first part but what are the SYN/ACK/FIN "bits"?

Comment: why you need low level programming for that?

Comment: I don't...it's a theoretical homework assignment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a nice website which can help you out. [here](http://www.pcvr.nl/tcpip/tcp_conn.htm) This photo shows a three-way handshake and a disconnection at the end. Notice the changing SYN and ACK numbers as the client and server exchange packets. FIN is the trigger for a disconnect. It can be sent by the client or the server. Source : http://www.pcvr.nl/tcpip/tcp_conn.htm

[image]